# How to access properties of inner function from outer function with javascript

Tags: javascript, this, scoping

I have declared variable at global level in function, which eventually get changed within inner function and I want to return changed variable value as outer function's value but currently getting undefined.Plz provide guidance.

```
function checkResult(req){
    let result = true;
    Reservation.find({result_date: req.body.res_date}, function (err,doc) {
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        else if (reservations) {
         result = false;
         console.log(result);       
        }
    })
    console.log("Final:");
    return result; // undefined error
}
```

Comment: What does reservation.find do? Most importantly, is it asynchronous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use callback.

For example:

```
function checkResult(req, callback){
    let result = true;
    Reservation.find({result_date: req.body.res_date}, function (err,doc) {
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        else if (reservations) {
            result = false;       
        }

        callback(result);
    })
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
checkResult(req, function(result){
    console.log(result); // prints the boolean
});
```

Comment: If the example works to you, can you accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

`Reservation.find` looks to take in a callback which is called upon completion.
If `Reservation.find` is asynchronous, then `checkResult` is telling `Reservation.find` to begin executing, and then will immediately return `result` (which is `undefined`).

In other words, `return result;` is executing *before* `result = false;` because everything inside of your anonymous function `function (err,doc)` happens out of the flow of the function execution.

Try performing any action that needs `result` within your callback (the `function (err,doc)` block).

Edit: which is what Kenji Mukai shows below